# Where are method-local variables stored?

Tags: java, concurrency, local-variables

I am having some questions related a very specific situation we can encounter when dealing with Singleton objects and concurrent call events.

I know there are other questions somehow related to mine, but they are not quite what I wanted to know. (example: [Concurrently invoking Java method of singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548417/concurrently-invoking-java-method-of-singleton-object))

Say for example I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass{
   private static MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();

   private new MyClass() {}

   public MyClass getInstance(){
      return myInstance;
   }

   public String doSomething(String message){
      java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
      System.out.println(message);
      System.out.println("Today is: " + d);
   }
}
```

In a concurrent scenario in which I am calling this same class instance many times I want to know what happens to the Date `d` variable, memory wise, will it be stored in a different memory stack for everyone that calls getInstance().doSomething()?

In my understanding since the class instance is static but it has no mutable global variables declared it should be creating separate `d` objects for different processes with no concurrency problems at all.

Could someone please clarify this part?

Comment: 'Singleton' and 'object' have nothing to do with this question. You are asking where Java puts local variables, and the answer is 'on the thread stack '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Each thread has it's own call stack and `d` reference placed on it. Object itself allocated in heap but JIT compiler may even place it on stack if during [escape analysis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) variable will be considered local. In your example there is no contention on `d` so `doSomething` may be considered thread-safe.

However you need to keep in mind that threads may interference with each other in case if "local" objects produce read/write operations to mutable shared state (for example writable static field).

Comment: Can you please explain how `read` operations are affected and how can I avoid thread interference in such occasions.